# Using SoX vad without an audio device

Tags: android-activity, detection, voice, sox

I am trying to use the SoX vad (voice activity detection) feature to analyze a wav file to determine if it contains speech (unsurprisingly.) However, I am using it on the command line on a Linux server that has no audio device. I would expect that I should be able run the command and capture the output somehow, but it seems like the vad feature is dependent on using the "play" command and that appears to be dependent on an audio device.

Is there a way that I can do this without an audio device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works here, how did you run it? Here's what I did:

```
sox infile.wav outfile.wav vad
```

`outfile.wav` is trimmed at the front until voice is detected.

Comment: Did you have an audio device installed on our system when you ran this? The problem I was encountering was that using the vad feature appeared to require that an audio device be present on the system. I didn't have an audio device on my system when I was trying to use the command.

Comment: @EdMcLaughlin: I tested it now with the sound disabled, i.e. sound drivers unloaded on a GNU/Linux system, without any problems.

Comment: Thanks, Thor. Not sure what I was doing wrong at the time, but looks like that works.